# Django: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with a CreateView in my Django app, I want to create a Sesion but the sessions can only be created by a GroupMember leader of that Group.

Here are my models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    # The code

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    assistants = models.ManyToManyField(GroupMember, through='SessionAssistant')
    hours = models.FloatField(default=1)
    day = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

class SessionAssistant(models.Model):
    assistant = models.ForeignKey(GroupMember)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    rol = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    assist = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Also I want when I create a Sesision I can assign de rols of my assistants, here is my view:

```
class CreateSession(CreateView):
    model = Session
    template_name = "session_form.html"
    fields = ['name',
              'hours',
              'day',
              'assistants', ]

    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        group = Group.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.group = group
        return super(CreateSession, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 3):

Django does not save custom `ManyToMany` relationships. Take a look to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

You can save your form using

```
form.save()
```

And then create a new objects from `SessionAssistant`

```
for assistant in form.cleaned_data['assistants']:
    SessionAssistant.objects.create(assistant=assistant, session=form.instance)
```